# Unique User ID for iOS

Tags: ios, swift

For my app, I want to be able to identify my user at the server end, for which I need a unique user identification on the device side. For Android, we are using Google sign-in. What can we use for iPhone? I don't want to use Google sign-in, as it is not native to iOS users. I want to use a native equivalent in the iOS ecosystem.

Comment: CUUID and NSUUID string works.. you can store it in the keychain so its persistent across installs..

Comment: @Bradon Is this one will be same if user install and uninstall app

Comment: Yes, it will be same you need to store in keychain.. search like this store uuid in keychain ios on google you will get solution from many links

Answer (score 7):

You can use CloudKit to access current user's Unique record/ID. This is supposed to be unique irrespective of the device as long user uses the same AppleID.

```
 let container = CKContainer.default()
 container.fetchUserRecordID { (recordId, error) in
     if error != nil {
         print("Handle error", error)
     } else{
         print("recordId", recordId, recordId.recordName)
     }
 }
```

You can also fetch more info like name, email, phone, etc but with additional permission

```
 container.requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
     container.discoverUserIdentity(withUserRecordID: recordId!, completionHandler: { (userID, error) in
                  print(userID?.hasiCloudAccount)
                  print(userID?.lookupInfo?.phoneNumber)
                  print(userID?.lookupInfo?.emailAddress)
                  print((userID?.nameComponents?.givenName)! + " " + (userID?.nameComponents?.familyName)!)
     })
 }
```

Make sure you enable iCloud/CloudKit services in your project Capabilities setting

Comment: Que!?  I didn't know that every iOS user is required to have an iCloud account.

Comment: That's right. If you're downloading apps from AppStore, most likely you'll have iCloud account. But ofcourse you've to handle error case above and fallback to vendor id or something similar

Comment: What are you talking about?  No iOS user is required to use an iCloud account.  I don't use it.

Comment: Where did I say it's "required"? "likely" was the keyword :) Some relevant info if you're interested: https://www.stuff.co.nz/technology/gadgets/72729126/apple-quietly-makes-icloud-optout-for-iphones-ipads

Answer (score 5):

Apple would tell you to use the [vendor Identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor):

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

It will be the same across all your apps on the device.

To answer about the notifications, you get an identifier in the delegate callback for those.

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

The deviceToken [is documented as](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications):

```
deviceToken
A globally unique token that identifies this device to APNs. Send this token to the server that you use to generate remote notifications. Your server must pass this token unmodified back to APNs when sending those remote notifications.

APNs device tokens are of variable length. Do not hard-code their size.
```

Comment: Is this one will be same if user install and uninstall app for same device? Can I use this for push notification?

Comment: I updated the answer to include how you get the deviceToken for use in remote notifications.